# Anuglar 5 - ng test is not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have created an angular project. When I run the "ng test" command I am facing the below error. Chrome is not getting opened. After trying to open it for couple of times, its getting crashed. Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue

```
09 05 2018 11:40:19.993:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, k
illing.
09 05 2018 11:40:20.039:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms
, killing.
09 05 2018 11:40:20.071:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
09 05 2018 11:40:21.262:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
09 05 2018 11:41:20.091:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms
, killing.
09 05 2018 11:41:20.125:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).
09 05 2018 11:41:21.274:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, k
illing.
09 05 2018 11:41:22.479:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
09 05 2018 11:42:20.130:WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms
, killing.
09 05 2018 11:42:20.169:ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS failed 2 times (timeout). Gi
ving up.
09 05 2018 11:42:22.483:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, k
illing.
09 05 2018 11:42:23.262:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Givin
g up.�
```

My Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "SampleProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --browsers=Chrome",
    "test-headless": "ng test --single-run=true --browsers=PhantomJS --reporters=progress,junit",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    <<All DEPENDENCIES ARE ADDED HERE>>
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.39",
    "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-typescript": "^3.0.12",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Do I need to configure anything else to get it run successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I too face same issue where chrome gets killed after two attempts with chrome version 66.

I have been trying same with **angular 5,karma 2.0.0, karma-chrome-launcher 2.2.0** on windows 10 machine and wasted entire day to figure it out why chrome is not capturing.

Could you please let me know whats the value of **autoWatch** and **singleRun** in **karma-conf.js** ??

If both values are **false** then
instead running **ng test**, run the command **ng test --single-run=true**

Check with results.

If results not as expected then share the karma-conf.js file to check further.